# unable to burn ubuntu 13.04 in mac

Tags: 13.04, iso

I can't burn ubuntu 13.04 iso on a dvd because it has a hybrid boot system and my mac doesn't recognize it. is there a way around it?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Are you unable burn the iso image? If so this might help: - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Burning_from_Mac_OS_X Or, are you unable to boot the DVD? - Details on getting around the EFI issue. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation Otherwise, could we have a few more details on how you are experiencing problems?

Comment: Check http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx

Comment: Also, When did it say it didn't recognize it, if it burns first then shows the message, It might not be able to "mount" it on the desktop - try the booting with the disk anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use a burning software for mac and do a 1to1 copy

I'm not a mac owner  you have to make a google query  or use

[This list](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/11-cddvd-burning-apps-for-mac/)

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem a few minutes ago...I noticed that the downloading of the ISO ended a little sooner than I thought. It said "10 mins left" in the browser, 766mb/785mb, and a second later it finished downloading and it wouldn't burn. Must be a problem with the ubuntu servers. I downloaded it from a torrent site (kat.ph) and it worked fine -- 5x faster download too.